# WKNavigationDelegate methods gets called at first load only

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I want to print url after navigation completes, I did it using

```
webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

function, but the problem is, for some websites like harrods.com it get called only once at first load of the website. I need Help. Any Solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this func of `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy)
```

and check the navigation type

`navigationAction.navigationType`

Comment: why should I check navigation type because I need to print url only, which I get from WKWebView object of given method. Thanks for help. It works :)

Comment: This function is called for different events, if you don't want to print url for all of them you can check the type before: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationtype

Comment: Ok, Thanks Patrick_K, & how can I trigger JavaScript function to get to know that if any particular button on webPage is clicked or not?